# Make uploader and upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, uwp

i'm using a simple code for uploading file into my website, here is my code:

```
protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/");

    if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

    FileUpload1.SaveAs(folderPath + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName));

    lblMessage.Text = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName) + " has been uploaded.<br/>"
       +"<br/>bytes: " + FileUpload1.FileBytes.Length
       + "<br/>Streams: "+ FileUpload1.FileContent.Length
       + "<br/>fName: " + FileUpload1.FileName;
}
```

FileUpload1 is System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload .
How can I upload files via C# code into my website?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload files you need to use a POST request of type "multipart/form-data".
Example code:

```
//create http client
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    //create the content we need
    using (var multipartFormDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        //read the file as bytes
        var bytes = //file content

        //wrap it into the formdata
        multipartFormDataContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(bytes));

        //do the post request and retrieve the response from the server
        var result = await client.PostAsync("myUrl.com", multipartFormDataContent);
    }
}
```